# How to build production environment with canary flags?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I would like to use one of canary flags currently available in `ember-data 2.4.0-beta.2`. When I use `ember serve` it works as expected. But with `ember build --prod` it throws error on code that requires that flag. I assume I have to enable it somewhere but didn't have any luck finding any documentation for it.

```
// I added flag into environment and made sure that it is not overridden on production
EmberENV: {
  FEATURES: {
    'ds-references': true
  }
},
```

Comment: I made workaround for it enabling minimization on new environment.

Comment: how exactly did you worked around it?

Comment: As far as I know `production` environment is just environment with enabled minification. So you can just create new environment and enable it.Check [asset-compilation](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation) for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bug that is fixed now. [Fixup feature flagging infrastructure.](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/4320)